# Iterate a list in Python with indexes and tags

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, arraylist, output

I'm trying to iterate over an output in python, but I would like to add the tags in a list to the file outputs.
I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request

list_animal = ["Dog","Bird","Cat","Dog","Bird","Cat","Dog","Bird","Cat","Dog","Bird","Cat"] 

def url_to_png(i,j, url, file_path):

    filename = 'image-{}.png'.format(i)
    full_path = '{}{}'.format(file_path, filename)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

    print('{} saved.'.format(filename))

    return None


FILENAME = 'C:\\Users\\Gary\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Python Scripts\\scrap_image - copia\\image_pandas.csv'
FILE_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\Gary\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Python Scripts\\scrap_image - copia\\imagenes_test/'

urls = pd.read_csv(FILENAME)
for i, url in enumerate(urls.values):       
    url_to_png(j,i, url[0], FILE_PATH)
```

The output is:

```
image-0.png saved.
image-1.png saved.
image-2.png saved.
image-3.png saved.
image-4.png saved.
```

I want something like this:

```
Dog_image-0.png saved.
Bird_image-1.png saved.
Cat_image-2.png saved.
Dog_image-3.png saved.
Bird_image-4.png saved.
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: with `filename = 'image-{}.png'.format(i)` you define the output format. `i` is the output from the indices of `enumerate`.

Comment: `filename = '{}_image-{}.png'.format(list_animal[i], i)`?

Comment: Thanks, i work for me